# Point to folder, not redirect htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have this htaccess, which redirects the user from stjernekaffe.dk to the directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://stjernekaffe.dk/am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [R=301,L]
```

I need it to point to the directory when entering stjernekaffe.dk, and shows the directory / file without redirecting the path / URL.

Is there any possiblity to make this happend?

I have this htaccess file in my /am/ folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /am
RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

And i have tried this (but it's like the /am -htaccess file does something wrong in the parent htaccess)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want **external redirection** (i.e. avoiding changing URL in browser) then make sure to:

1. Do not use `R` flag in RewriteRule
2. Do not use full URL that starts with `http` in the target URL

With above suggestion change your code in DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [L]
```

change your code in DOCUMENT_ROOT/am/.htaccess to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /am/

RewriteRule ^public/?$ public.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it redirects my page to /am only.

Comment: I have a htaccess file in the /am/, maybe that cause the problem? <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /am
    RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: Its difficult to read code in comments, can you pls post this to your question?

Comment: Yes you have couple of issues in your `/am/.htaccess` file let me post a suggested file for that as well.

Comment: It says file not found /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr

Comment: That's expected since that's you wanted to achieve as per your original question `RewriteRule (.*) http://stjernekaffe.dk/am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [R=301,L]`

Comment: I don't understand, so it's not impossible?

Comment: Ok back to square one. To which URL you want to forward if someone enters: `http://stjernekaffe.dk/` ?

Comment: When i am entering stjernekaffe.dk it has to forward to stjernekaffe.dk/am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr just without the url changes. stjernekaffe.dk/am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr has to be stjernekaffe.dk

Comment: That's what my answer is already doing. If you directly enter `http://stjernekaffe.dk/am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr` in your browser what do you see?

Comment: Then i see the content of the what i need to see. But getting Not Found

The requested URL /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr was not found on this server. when entering the primary domain stjernekaffe.dk

Comment: Ok just for testing purpose: change this rule: `RewriteRule ^$ /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [L]` to this: `RewriteRule ^$ /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [R,L]`

Comment: It just redirect again to the url with new URL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30573/discussion-between-anubhava-and-kim-larsen)

Comment: That means rules are working fine. Can you try: `RewriteRule ^$ /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [P,L]` now.

Comment: No, it's Aweber, i exactly don't know :-/

Comment: So most likely that framework is looking at your REQUEST_URI to be: `/am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr` and then internally loading the correct page. When we forward via .htaccess to `/am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr` it throws page not found since REQUEST_URI is just `/` and framework doesn't know where to forward. I was hoping proxy: `RewriteRule ^$ /am/signup/index/c/QBYEYjDr [P]` will work for you but that also didn't work.